# Tricky Limit question

Tags: limits

What is

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{t^3}-1-t^3}{\sin(t^2)-t^2}?$$

I used Hopital's rule, but it kept getting more complicated!

Comment: Maybe try taylor series expansions

Answer (score 5):

You would need to apply De l'Hôpital's Rule six (!) times before obtaining an answer.

From the Taylor expansions, we know $\sin(t^2) = t^2 - \dfrac{t^6}{3!} + O(t^{10})$ and $\exp(t^3) = 1 + t^3 + \dfrac{t^6}{2!} +  O(t^9)$.

Thus, the quotient becomes:

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{e^{t^3}-1-t^3}{\sin(t^2)-t^2} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{t^6/2! + O(t^9)}{t^6/3! + O(t^{10})} = \frac{3!}{2!} = 3$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
Use Taylor's formula for $x\to{0}$:
$$e^{x}=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\ldots+\dfrac{x^n}{n!}+o(x^n), \\
\sin{x}=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\ldots+(-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{{(2n+1)}!}+o(x^{2n+1}).$$

Answer (score 2):

Write it up as 
$$\frac{t^6}{\sin (t^2) - t^2} \cdot \frac{e^{t^3} - 1 - t^3}{t^6 }$$

For first use L'hopital rule three times and you will get [this value](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bx%5E6%2C+%7Bx%2C+3%7D%5D%2FD%5Bsin%28x%5E2%29-x%5E2%2C+%7Bx%2C3%7D%5D). Similarly use L'hopital rule 4 times you will get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bx%5E6%2C+%7Bx%2C+4%7D%5D%2FD%5Be%5E%28x%5E3%29-x%5E3+-+1%2C+%7Bx%2C4%7D%5D) for the second. Of course, Taylor expansion is much easier.